# Кликабельная область для StretchyIcon

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Использую https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Placemark-docpage/ с `preset: 'islands#nightStretchyIcon'`. Кликабельной оказывается только область над "хвостиком" иконки, текст не кликается вообще.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? Как побороть?

Comment: В каком браузере воспроизводится? У меня всё хорошо https://jsfiddle.net/wgxd0xqs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге дело оказалось в вёрстке, а именно в `overflow-x` и ининциализации карты в фоне.